# Android: cannot find Resource (string-array) from id in page adapter

Tags: android, resources

I made an app in which there is a ViewPager working with a subclass of PagerAdapter I made, everything was working fine but some strings were hard-coded and I decided to put them in the resources but this brought some problems, this error shows up when I try to retrieve a string array for the "getPageTitle" method of my PagerAdapter.

The error:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String array resource ID #0x7f030002

getPageTitle in my PagerAdapter :

```
@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    String[] tabTitles = Resources.getSystem().getStringArray(R.array.days_short_names);
    return tabTitles[position];
}
```

Yet the resource does exist, here it is in string_arrays.xml :

```
<string-array name="days_short_names">
    <item>@string/monday_short</item>
    <item>@string/tuesday_short</item>
    <item>@string/wednesday_short</item>
    <item>@string/thursday_short</item>
    <item>@string/friday_short</item>
    <item>@string/saturday_short</item>
    <item>@string/sunday_short</item>
</string-array>
```

Plus the strings in strings.xml :

```
<string name="monday_short">Mon</string>
<string name="tuesday_short">Tue</string>
<string name="wednesday_short">Wed</string>
<string name="thursday_short">Thu</string>
<string name="friday_short">Fri</string>
<string name="saturday_short">Sat</string>
<string name="sunday_short">Sun</string>
```

I even checked in the R class and it is there so I'm kinda clueless about why it doesn't work.

in R.java :

```
public static final class array {
    public static final int context_menu_actions=0x7f030000;
    public static final int days_long_names=0x7f030001;
    public static final int days_short_names=0x7f030002;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're trying to access the array from another class that is not an activity, so you use: `Resources.getSystem().getStringArray(R.array.days_short_names);`  
If it's possible get the context of an activity or from getApplicationContext() as a parameter to your class's constructor and use:

```
context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.days_short_names);
```